# Calculate the difference between two dates in seconds using the date program?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, date

How would I calculate the difference between two dates, for example, "January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC" and "November 23, 2019, at 00:00:00 PST" in **seconds** using the date program?

Answer (score 2):

```
]# date --date='November 23 2019 00:00:00 PST' +%s
1574496000
```

One and a half Gigaseconds. I checked it roughly by calculating back.

```
]# echo $((2019 - 1574496000/(60*60*24*365)))
1970
```

---

> for example, "January 1, 1970,...

Maybe this makes some people downvote, because 1.1.1970 is the "zero" date, not an example. Like asking: *how to calculate the number of years since, for example, the year "0".*

Comment: Nah, I, and probably others, down voted because of lack of research. This question is a regular here

Answer (score 1):

Simple extension to answer the general question. Run both dates (against the 1970-01-01 epoch) with +%s, then subtract the seconds. Divide by 86400 to get days.

You might want to think about timezones and daylight saving. For whole days, I usually force the times to 12:00:00 which avoids most of those issues.